# Split pelo caractere | não retorna todos os elementos esperados

Tags: java

Tenho um arquivo com linhas semelhantes a apresentada a seguir:

```
42|a|b|c|d||f||h|||||||||||||||||||
```

Preciso fazer split pelo caracter | então meu código faz da seguinte maneira:

```
String linha42 = "42|a|b|c|d||f||h|||||||||||||||||||";
String[] campos = linha42.split(Pattern.quote("|"));

for(String item : campo){
    System.out.println("item: " + item);
}
```

Porém quando eu percorro os campos ele para de fazer o split na letra h, como se não reconhecesse os demais.

Ex da saída:

```
item: 42
item: a
item: b
item: c
item: d
item: 
item: f
item: 
item: h
```

Alguma sugestão ?

Comment: Você precisa que apareçam caracteres vazios em todos os que vêm após o h?

Comment: Sim, mesmo que não tenha nada entre o | preciso identificar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

De acordo com [a documentação do `split`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String,%20int%29), basta passar um inteiro negativo como segundo parâmetro da chamada para receber tantos resultados quanto forem possíveis (o que, no fundo, é o que você quer).

Portanto, ficaria assim:

```
String linha42 = "42|a|b|c|d||f||h|||||||||||||||||||";
String[] campos = linha42.split(Pattern.quote("|"), -1);

for(String item : campos){
    System.out.println("item: " + item);
}
```

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente com esta solução do valor negativo, obrigado.